# Call to remote JVM using cmd script

Tags: java, jvm

I need to call a jar which is kept on a shared windows machine.
The JVM also needs to be placed on this shared machine so that anyone with access to the remote location should be able to call this jar.

I need to write a windows script which shall be run using a service user.

Is this possible? If yes, request you to please provide pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Java Management Extensions provides the tools for building Web-based, distributed, dynamic and modular solutions for managing and monitoring devices, applications, and service-driven networks.

see [JMX Tutorial](http://www.academictutorials.com/jmx/)

see [example with Linux script](http://www.devdaily.com/blog/post/java/source-code-java-jmx-hello-world-application)

see [Windows cmd script](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Programming/Programming_CMD)

Answer (score 0):

You might have some luck using the [Tanuki Software](http://www.tanukisoftware.com/) [Java Service Wrapper](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/download.jsp). [Jetty](http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/) uses this for their [Windows Service Wrapper](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Win32Wrapper).

Another option is [Apache Commons Procrun](https://commons.apache.org/daemon/procrun.html), which is what [Apache Tomcat uses](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/windows-service-howto.html).

Both work well to set up a Java application as a Windows service. You will need to ensure your application is designed to run well as a service; you should be able to "trigger" events (start, stop, restart, etc.). You might need a lightweight adapter around the application to get it to work right as a service; but that should be a trivial exercise.

Once you have a service set up, make sure appropriate user(s) have rights to start/stop the service [[1]](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/288129) [[2]](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/325349). You could even set the service up to run using a specific account. Then you can use the `net start`, `net stop`, etc. [commands](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc736564%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) in a batch file.